# how dose mysql(InnoDB) chose a proper index?

Tags: mysql

There is a KEY `idx_from_to_created_ts`(`from`,`to`,`created_ts`).
And the query sql like this:

```
select * from trade_orders where from = 'HK' and to='BJ' and created_ts>1504972800;
```

The query conditions match the KEY idx_from_to_created_ts perfectly.
But in fact, another KEY which seems not so good is chosen.
The explain:
[image]

Comment: Question is too big but basically the optimizer decides https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer.html for an 'interesting' read.

Comment: Maybe the other index *is* better? MySQL seems to think that - according to the `explain`, the choosen index is fine. Maybe because `to` is unique, or because the index includes all columns, or idx_from_to_created_ts isn't usable after all or is larger than it needs to be - but if you do not add the table definition, we cannot check for you. Also: do you actually only get one row, or is MySQL wrong here?